# JavaScript: How to make a prototype function with parameters

Tags: javascript

This is my first time using prototypes in JavaScript and I could use some help.

I have a class that is like

```
    function snakegame(C, C_w, C_h, Ls, spd)
    {
           // .... bunch of other stuff ...

            this.boxCollision = function(A, B)
            {
                return A.x == B.x && A.y == B.y;
            }

           // ... bunch of other stuff here too ...

    }
```

and I want to prototype the `boxCollision` function, i.e. define it inside `snakegame` and then write the implementation outside. I tried

```
    function snakegame(C, C_w, C_h, Ls, spd)
    {
           // .... bunch of other stuff ...

            this.boxCollision(A, B);


           // ... bunch of other stuff here too ...

    }

    snakegame.prototype.boxCollision = function(A, B) 
    {
         return A.x == B.x && A.y == B.y;
    }
```

but that didn't work.

I also tried writing `this.boxCollision(var, var)` for the prototype, but that didn't work either. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Well, how did you call `boxCollision` in the first case? `this.boxCollision(A, B);` only works if `A` and `B` are defined. The problem doesn't seem to be with the prototype but with how you call the method. The arguments you are passing to it have to exist (like with any other function, prototype or not).

Comment: you dont need to define. you can implement directly. i,e remove the line this.boxCollision(A, B); and it will work as you want.

Comment: Btw, I recommend to read some documentation about this topic, like MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

You would want to do something like this:

```
var SnakeGame = function () {
  //Constructor code
};

SnakeGame.prototype = new Object(); //Or what ever object you are going to inherit from

SnakeGame.prototype.boxCollision = function() {
  //code
};

SnakeGame.prototype.otherFunction = ...
```

Then to use it do this:

```
var mySnakeGame = new SnakeGame();
mySnakeGame.boxCollision();
```

Also, it is important to use capitalization on your objects, SnakeGame not snakegame. It is convention and will help you keep things straight.

This [site](http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/) also has some more info if you'd like to learn more about prototyping in JavaScript.